# Block auto-format ignore command in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, formatting, keyboard-shortcuts

I love using the Auto Formatting tool in Visual Studio <kbd>CTRL K + CTRL D</kbd> However, there are times when VS makes the formatting just a tad off from what I want if, for instance, I'm making a detailed kind of pseudo-code that relies on specific comments and indentation. Is there a way I can still use the <kbd>CTRL K + CTRL D</kbd> command and set visual studio to ignore a certain block of code or set of line numbers? Also, if there's an answer in VS 2013 but not in 2012, please post because I may be upgrading soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer your question, no there isn't (not even in 2013), but if you really want this you can write an extension that does so (look into implementing IOleCommandTarget and filtering for the format document command).

Answer (score 3):

I got hit by this problem today with my **pseudo-code comments** too and thought I'd share the way I solved it.

While there is no way to prevent Visual Studio from auto-formatting parts of code, **there is a way to prevent it from auto-formatting pseudo-code comments**.

Instead of using something this like this

```
  // if condition
     // do this
  // else
     // do something else
```

use the tripple-slashes `///` instead

```
  /// if condition
  ///    do this
  /// else
  ///    do something else
```

As a bonus you get **automatic insertion of `///`** in new lines and **auto-indenting** that keeps previous row's indentation level.

This seems not to depend on editor indentation options.
It also seems not to mess up XML documentation

*(Yes, I know this is an old question. No, I do not want to take Cameron's right for accepted answer.)*